# Simulating Java imports in C++

Tags: java, c++, compiler-construction

I am trying to translate a subset of Java to c++. How can i simulate imports(single and on-demand) in c++ ?

Comment: Before you  get ahead of yourself: How many *other* parts of this project have you figured out?

Comment: C++ Is predominately a staticly linked language, although you can dynamically link and import functionality through .so's -- however to get any real answer to your question, you probably need to supply us with a bit of code for the specific functionaly you want to implement.

Comment: @Soren Nice comment overall <nitpick>, but I'd change "through .so's" to "through .so's on *nix or .dll's on Windows"</nitpick>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java allows classes to use each other in their definitions, c++ does not:

```
class A{
 B m(){return new B();}
}
class B{
 A b(){return new A();}
}
```

So I guess it is not possible to retain the same import structure.

Easiest way - grab some java to c++ converter and look through the code it generates, might be useful.

Answer (score -3):

C++ only supports `#include`s for entire libraries. You can't `#include` parts of it.

However, if the library contains namespaces, you can add a `using` for the classes (or namespaces) that you want to use directly without adding namespace resolution every time.

Comment: You can include anything you want. Even the same file twice.

Comment: @mabn: At least I'm sure that it's not possible to include the same file twice (unless with precompiler headers).